# PlotLy JS: Custom Legend : How to draw customer legend having values coming form X-AXIS

Tags: plotly

I am using Plotly Js to design my graphs using the following graphs

```
var trace1 = {
  x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
  y: [20, 14, 23],
 name: 'SF Zoo',
 type: 'bar',
 showlegend: true
};

var data = [trace1];
var layout = {barmode: 'group'};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

This is what i am getting currently:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8voT.png)

But i want: Legends as coming from X-AXIS values
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSNyX.png)

Comment: I mean, Legend values should be coming from X-AXIS